# How do I trade with villagers?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was just wondering how you can 'trade' with villagers in minecraft. I know it was added in 1.3, but I can't figure out how to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://minecraft.wiki/w/Trading :

> "Right-clicking on a villager will open a GUI allowing a player to trade with the villager. Villagers will make offers based on their profession and career, and will only make trades based on what offers they are making"

Answer (score 0):

You just right-click (or whatever your 'use block' is set to) a villager, and it will open up the trade GUI. You put the item(s) in the left slot(s), and pull out the item offered from the right slot. Also, trading increases popularity, if you were not aware of this before.